Combining functions in powerapps
this is my first post and probably a very easy solve, i have imported a list of data into sharepoint which is then referenced in a gallery within my Power app. I am trying to sort the data so the Drawing number is decreasing from the top, alongside this i have two text boxes which can be used to filter the data. I have managed to get the two to work, however when i try to use them together i get an error. I have pasted both sets of code.
Filter(
  Drawings,
  StartsWith('DRAWING NUMBER',txtsearch.Text),
  StartsWith('Job Number',JobNumSearch.Text))

Sort(testlist,'DRAWING NUMBER',SortOrder.Descending)

Thanks in advance.
I have tried both sets of code seperately and go them both to function as expected.

Both Filter and Sort functions take a table as an input, and return a table as an output, so you can combine them by nesting one inside the other:
Sort(
    Filter(
        Drawings,
        StartsWith('DRAWING NUMBER',txtsearch.Text),
        StartsWith('Job Number',JobNumSearch.Text)),
    'DRAWING NUMBER',
    SortOrder.Descending)

In this case, the result of the Filter will be used as the input to the Sort function.
